# How to define the same field for load_only and dump_only params at the Marshmallow scheme?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow

I am trying to build a marshmallow scheme to both load and dump data. And I get everything OK except one field.

#### Problem description

(If you understand the problem, you don't have to read this).

For load data its type is `Decimal`. And I used it like this before. Now I want to use this schema for dumping and for that my flask API responses with: `TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`. OK, I understand. I changed the type to `Float`. Then my legacy code started to get an exception while trying to save that field to database (it takes `Decimal` only). I don't want to change the legacy code so I looked for any solution at the marshmallow docs and found `load_only` and `dump_only` params. It seems like those are what I wanted, but here is my problem - I want to set them to the same field. So I just wondered if I can define both fields and tried this:

```py
class PaymentSchema(Schema):
    money = fields.Decimal(load_only=True)
    money = fields.Float(dump_only=True)
```

I have been expected for a miracle, of course. Actually I was thinking that it will skip first definition (correctly, re-define it). What I got is an absence of the field at all.

#### Workaround solution

So I tried another solution. I created another schema for dump and inherit it from the former schema:

```py
class PaymentSchema(Schema):
    money = fields.Decimal(load_only=True)

class PaymentDumpSchema(PaymentSchema):
    money = fields.Float(dump_only=True)
```

It works. But I wonder if there's some another, native, "marshmallow-way" solution for this. I have been looking through the docs but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### pass `data_key` argument to the field definition

[Documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html) mentions, `data_key` parameter can be used along with `dump_only` or `load_only` to be able to have same field with different functionality. `attribute` parameter's value will refer the field with its original field name.

So you can write your schema as...

```py
class PaymentSchema(Schema):
    decimal_money = fields.Decimal(data_key="money", load_only=True, attribute="money")
    money = fields.Float(dump_only=True)
```

This should solve your problem. I am using `data_key` for similar problem in marshmallow with `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` and this fixed my issue.

**Note:** The key in `ValidationError.messages` (error messages) will be `decimal_money` by default. You may tweak the `handle_error` method of Schema class to replace `decimal_money` with `money` but it is not recommended as you yourself may not be able to differentiate between the error messages fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a best solution. Thank you! Can't check it right now, alas.

Comment: Okay, test it and if works out then kindly accept answer & upvote so that it could come on the top :)

Comment: change second line to `decimal_money = fields.Decimal(data_key="money", load_only=True, attribute='money')`, remove `Edit` part and I will accept your answer. I tested it. `data_key` does half of the trick (it gets value from `money` field), the other part is to rename `decimal_money` to `money` which `attribute` does. Thank you for your solution!

Comment: @egvo Yes, thanks for reminding about attribute. I used attribute field as I wanted to relate `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` field with Model, but did not mention here before. 
I have added necessary changes in answer now as suggested. Glad that it helped, You may accept now :)

Comment: are you sure about `Note` part considering last changes?

Comment: Yes I was working on it and came across error dictionary part, so I added that note in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the marshmallow decorator @pre_load in this decorator you can do whatever you want and return with your type

```
from marshmallow import pre_load
```

import like this and in this you will get your payload and change the type as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**: I found a good solution finally.

## NEW SOLUTION

The trick is to define your field in `load_fields` and `dump_fields` inside `__init__` method.

```
from marshmallow.fields import Integer, String, Raw
from marshmallow import Schema


class ItemDumpLoadSchema(Schema):
    item = Raw()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not (self.only and 'item' not in self.only) and \
                not (self.exclude and 'item' in self.exclude):
            self.load_fields['item'] = Integer(missing=0)
            self.dump_fields['item'] = String()
```

Usage:

```
>>> ItemDumpLoadSchema().load({})
{'item': 0}
>>> ItemDumpLoadSchema().dump({'item': 0})
{'item': '0'}
```

Don't forget to define field in a schema with some field (`Raw` in my example) - otherwise it may raise an exception in some cases (e.g. using of `only` and `exclude` keywords).

## OLD SOLUTION

A little perverted one. It based on @prashant-suthar answer. I named load field with suffix `_load` and implemented `@pre_load`, `@post_load` and error handling.

```
class ArticleSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.String()
    title = fields.String()
    text = fields.String()
    
    
class FlowSchema(Schema):
    article = fields.Nested(ArticleSchema, dump_only=True)
    article_load = fields.Int(load_only=True)

    @pre_load
    def pre_load(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if data.get('article'):
            data['article_load'] = data.pop('article')
        return data

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if data.get('article_load'):
            data['article'] = data.pop('article_load')
        return data

    def handle_error(self, exc, data, **kwargs):
        if 'article_load' in exc.messages:
            exc.messages['article'] = exc.messages.pop('article_load')
        raise exc
```

#### Why the old solution is not a good solution?

It doesn't allow to inheritate schemas with different `handle_error` methods defined. And you have to name `pre_load` and `post_load` methods with different names.